# Percent of bitcoin transactions not to exchanges?

Tags: bitcoin-economy, speculation, volume

Is there any way to estimate the percentage of bitcoin transaction volume that isn't related to speculation? For example, one could estimate the volume sent to and received from the major exchanges and look at how that compares to the total transaction volume.